# Links for routes with prefixes

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm using latest Laravel 5.4. My site is configured to use German and English languages. So for instance, I have a login page for German:

```
http://localhost/de/login
```

and for English:

```
http://localhost/en/login
```

What I've done is I created a Language middleware that looks at the first segment of the URI ('en' or 'de') and sets proper `app()->setLocale()` based on the first segment value. What I'm struggling with is how do I generate links (properly / best practice) for such routes. What function should I use in my blade templates to generate such links. I tried `route('login', app()->getLocale())` but it's giving me something like this: `http://localhost/en/login?de`. Why is this happening? What's the function I should be using to generate links to named routes and unnamed routes?

Thanks,
Z

Comment: You dont really need dedicated locale appended path. Locale is maintained using session variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Route::post('page/{locale?}', 'PageController@someMethod')->where(['locale' => 'de|en|es|fr|it|nl']);
```

See, if this works!

Comment: Ok, let me remove optional solution.